# How to use custom created methods of a string prototype?

Tags: javascript

I created my own method which basically capitalizes the first alphabet of every word in a string.

However, I am getting this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` error. Where am I wrong?

```js
String.prototype.toCapitalize = (str) => {
  let splits = str.split(" ");
  let capitalize = '';
  splits.forEach((el) => {
    let result = el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1, el.length).toLowerCase();
    capitalize = capitalize + ' ' + result;
  });
  return capitalize;
}
let h = 'its a beautiful weather';
h.toCapitalize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues. The function takes a parameter of `str`, but you're not calling it with any parameter. The conventional way to reference the instantiated object you're calling a method on is to use `this`, but you have an arrow function - better to use a standard function so you can use `this`:

```js
String.prototype.toCapitalize = function() {
  let splits = this.split(" ");
  let capitalize = '';
  splits.forEach((el) => {
    let result = el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1, el.length).toLowerCase();
    capitalize = capitalize + ' ' + result;
  });
  return capitalize;
}
let h = 'its a beautiful weather';
console.log(h.toCapitalize());
```

But mutating the built-in objects is *terrible* practice - consider using a standalone function instead:

```js
const toCapitalize = str => str
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase())
  .join(' ');
let h = 'its a beautiful weather';
console.log(toCapitalize(h));
```

Comment: Thanks! And then I can't use arrow functions lol. Doesn't matter!

Comment: If you use a standalone function rather than mutating the built-in prototype, you can (and should) use an arrow function

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! Gotcha! Will be marking as answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Sanjay You could have asked me the same question, doh! `:P`

Comment: Don't mind but @CertainPerformace has less reputation than yours so I will be marking his as an answer. Justified :P

Comment: @Sanjay Ha ha... Nice justification... `:)`

Answer (score 3):

How did you think that the first argument is the string? It is supposed to be `this`. Replacing `str` with `this` and works:

```js
String.prototype.toCapitalize = function () {
  let splits = this.split(" ");
  let capitalize = '';
  splits.forEach((el) => {
    let result = el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1, el.length).toLowerCase();
    capitalize = capitalize + ' ' + result;
  });
  return capitalize;
}
let h = 'its a beautiful weather';
console.log(h.toCapitalize());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `toCapitalize` as `h.toCapitalize()` then you need to use `this.split(" ");` as you are getting an error of `str` is not defined in console:

```js
String.prototype.toCapitalize = function() {
  let splits = this.split(" ");
  let capitalize = '';
  splits.forEach((el) => {
    let result = el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1, el.length).toLowerCase();
    capitalize = capitalize + ' ' + result;
  });
  return capitalize;
}
let h = 'its a beautiful weather';
console.log(h.toCapitalize());
```

Else, if you want to use the parameter `str` in the `toCapitalize` function then you need to call it as `st.toCapitalize(h)` where `st` can be any string type value.

```js
String.prototype.toCapitalize = function(str) {
  let splits = str.split(" ");
  let capitalize = '';
  splits.forEach((el) => {
    let result = el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1, el.length).toLowerCase();
    capitalize = capitalize + ' ' + result;
  });
  return capitalize;
}
let st ='';
let h = 'its a beautiful weather';
console.log(st.toCapitalize(h));
```